# Cs50 pset4 reflect image filter code problem

Tags: c, filter, cs50, image-manipulation

I'm working on the cs50 pset4 exercise filter, and I finished the grayscale filter and the sepia filter, and now I'm on the reflect filter. I'm supposed to reflect this image horizontally:

**NORMAL**

[image]

But all I get is this:

**REFLECT**

[image]

I don't know what's wrong. I tried to do it like in the video. In my code, i tried putting the right-side pixels into a temporary variable, then placing the left-side pixels into their place, then taking the right-side pixels out and putting them into the left-side pixel spot. Here's my code(reflect part only):

```c
// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < height;j++)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < width/2;i++)
    {
        RGBTRIPLE temp = image[j][i];
       image[j][width - i] = image[i][j];
       temp = image[j][width - i];
       
    }
    }
  
    return;
}
```

Please help me understand. When I googled it, all I got was either something different or the answer to the whole exercise, which is just copy-pasting from google.

Thanks a lot,
Lost in code:)

Comment: Did you confuse X and Y?

Comment: Which x and y? I don't have a variable name x nor y in my program.

Comment: You overwrite `image[j][width - i]` before saving it. While you overwrite it with a value you did save. But I do not think that can produce the shown effect...

Comment: Maybe you should use speaking variable names like `x` and `y` in a 2D picture, instead of ì` and `j`.

Comment: `width - i` should be `width - i - 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RGBTRIPLE temp = image[j][i];
image[j][width - i] = image[i][j];
temp = image[j][width - i];
```

is wrong because

- Pixel that isn't saved is overwritten instead of overwriting saved pixel.
- You won't want to use `image[i][j]` instead of `image[j][i]` here.
- `width - i` should be `width - i - 1`. For example, when `i = 0`, `width - i` will be `width` and it is out-of-range.
- You overwrote `temp` twice instead of assigning new values to two pixels.

It should be:

```
RGBTRIPLE temp = image[j][i];
image[j][i] = image[j][width - i - 1];
image[j][width - i - 1] = temp;
```

Comment: Sometimes, if an answer appears and all other answers receive downvotes in quick succession, the author of that single answer DID in fact downvote all others. But in this case, I want to applaud you for a) having a reason other than tactics b) doing it politely and with not required but freely given explanation, c) really helping with improving the downvoted answers d) actually undownvoting after some effort on that feedback. I admit  at initially being very annoyed. But now I admire the effort you put into this. Thanks. (excuse me, technically I still only assume that the downvote was by you)

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite image[j][width - i] before saving it
and you have one case of swapped i,j.

I recommend to swap the order of saving, overwriting and restoring.

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x  < width/2; x++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE temp = image[y][width -1 - x]; //save what gets overwritten

            // then overwrite
            image[y][width -1 - x] = image[y][x]; // note the wrong i,j which was here before
            
            // then overwrite the other with what was saved
            image[y][x] = temp;
        }
    }
  
    return;
}
```

The problem is the [i][j] you had. It should have been [j][i].
With names x,y that kind of problem is easier spotted.

Thanks, MikeCat, for pointing out the off-by-one mistake I made.

Comment: Using `image[y][width - x]` is wrong here because it will become out-of-range `image[y][width]` when `x = 0`.

Comment: You have one more `image[y][width - i]`

Comment: Also `i` should be `x`

Comment: I spotted that one myself. ;-)

Comment: I want to clarify, I meant "Mom" as "a moment please", not as "mommy", which could only be understood as something sarcastic here, which was not my intention...